# How can I change a default oh-my-zsh command alias?

Tags: alias, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I would like to use `exa` ([github](https://github.com/ogham/exa)) as a replacement for the default `ls`. I have gotten used to typing `ll`, `l` or `ls` and would like to alias `exa` accordingly.

But when trying to override the alias in the `.zshrc` zsh default back to the usual `ls` upon reloading and ignores the override.

Tried the follwing in my `.zshrc`'without sucess:

```sh
alias ls="exa -lahF"
alias l="exa -lahF"
alias ll="exa -lahF"
```

Is it possible to change the default alias and if so, how?

FIXED: Define aliases in .zshrc after `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "default" alias, but aliases stack. If you have an alias

```
alias l='ls -lahF'
```

and an alias

```
alias ls=exa
```

Then `l` will expand to `exa -lahF`.

Comment: Thanks, i did not realize this. Sadly this does not fix the issue.

```
alias ls='exa -lahF'
alias l='ls'
alias ll='ls'
```
Still, ls, l and ll default to their behaviour as defined by oh-my-zsh.

Comment: Fixed it now: Issue was that i defined aliases and sourced oh-my-zsh.sh right afterwards. Had to define alias after sourcing.

Comment: Please mark the question as closed by checking the green tick on the answer.